# Phase diagram from a list of points sharing different labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a two lists `x` and `y` , corresponding to the possible values of two parameters, for example

```
x=[1.,1.,1.,2.,2.,2.,3.,3.,3.]
y=[1.,2.,3.,1.,2.,3.,1.,2.,3.]
```

I also have a list `l` giving a label to each point `(x[i],y[i])` where `i` is an integer between `0` and `len(x)-1`. Suppose each point can have one of 3 labels:

```
l=[2,3,3,1,1,2,3,1,2]
```

In this example, the point `(1.,1.)` has the label `2`, the point `(1.,2.)` the label `3` and so on.

I need to make a phase diagram `x` vs `y` in which areas surrounding points with the same label will have a precise color. For example, areas containing only points `(x[j],y[j])` such that `l[j]=1` for all `j` shall be green, while for `l[j]=2` shall be red, `l[j]=3` shall be blue.

The color of those regions containing no points is arbitrary, but the boundaries between different regions should be as smooth as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`, `matplotlib.patches.Polygon`, and `matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection`:

```
# create data frame for better handling data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'l':l})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# containing hulls and colors to plot
hulls = []
colors = []
for i in set(l):
    hull = ConvexHull(df.loc[df.l==i, ['x','y']]).points
    hulls.append(Polygon(hull))
    colors.append(i)

# create patches collection and set color
p = PatchCollection(hulls, alpha=0.4)
p.set_array(np.array(colors))

ax.add_collection(p)

ax.scatter(df.x,df.y)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]